# Generate time-series synthetic data in R

Tags: r, time-series

I have power consumption data of few electrical appliances (like AC, Refrigerator, and Microwave ) as shown in below plots. Now, I want to generate synthetic data for these appliances. In the synthetic data generation process:

1. How can I generate data corresponding to first figure? Where states are of different duration (widths) and varying magnitude (heights).
2. How can I restrict the appliance usage for a specific time portion? For example, first figure corresponds to AC. This shows that AC works only after 11  PM till 8 AM of next day. Can I enforce such time restrictions during data generation
3. How to ensure some random usage? For example, In second figure we find several sudden usages of 500 watts for few minutes.
4. There are some appliances which consume power differently at different times, for example, third figure shows microwave usage which consumes anything between 100 to 800 watts.

What all the functions/approaches should I use to generate this type of time-series data [image],
[image],
[image]